# update_field not working onclick

Tags: javascript, php, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom field called `count`.  I am trying to increase and save its value to a post when a vote button is clicked for the image of the post.  However, it doesn't update the value of custom field nor does it update on the page...nothing happens

```
     <?php 
        // Query the custom post type to display
            $args = array('post_type' => 'books');
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
                    $query->the_post();
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): 
                    $oldcount=get_field('count');
                    $newcount=$oldcount+1;
        ?>


          <div><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?><button onclick="myvote($post_id,$newcount)">Vote</button><?php echo " ".$oldcount;?></div>

        <?php endif; endwhile; ?>

   <script language="Java Script" type="text/javascript">
    function myvote($pid,$tempcount) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/voteajax.php",
        data: {action:'call_this',pid:$pid,tempcount:$tempcount},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("body").append(html);
         }
       });
    };
    </script>
```

voteajax.php

```
<?php
   if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
   update_field('field_5501', $_POST['tempcount'],$_POST['pid']; 
   }
?>
```

Comment: So, where's the `update_field()` function to go with this; or is that irrelevant?

Comment: Is a request being sent to the server? Is this code getting run?

Comment: is that PHP inside the onclick??

Comment: Using php in an `onclick` wont work like that. you should be using ajax.  Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick) question

Comment: ok i altered the code but now it function automatically increases the count for all images to 1 whether clicked or not

Comment: @MichaelDoye o just added ajax and updated the code...nothing happens...still doesn't work.