# Use html to call/use php function

Tags: php, html, function, onclick

I'm having some trouble getting my `HTML` and `php` to work together.

I've made a `onClick` that should run a `PHP function` i have in the top of the `PHP` file. But every time i click it, it says: `ReferenceError: deleteSub is not defined`. Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

HTML:

```
<?php
                if(mysql_num_rows($sql_select_delete) > 0){
                     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select_delete)){
                         ?><div class="abo_box">
                           <label class="abo_navn" id="<? echo $row["id"]; ?>"><? echo $row['abo_name'];  ?></label>
                           <label class="delete" onclick="deleteSub();">Delete</label>
                         </div>
                         <?php
                     }
                }
           ?>
```

PHP:

```
function deleteSub(){
      echo "deleted";
 }
```

Comment: With onClick, you're calling a JS function not php. You can't do this without a refresh or ajax call.

Comment: onClick call javascript function, not PHP function...

Comment: Okay? I googled it before posting, and found a stackoverflow where this was the "right anwser"(cant find the link agian. sorry). I might have been reading it wrong tho, looks like it. Is there a way to do this then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick

Comment: Thanks @Zdenek Leitkep for your link. That helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call directly a PHP code like this
What you can do is to create a javascript function and you need to use Ajax witch will send a request to your re server and here you can call your PHP function
Remember : PHP is server side code and HTML, JS is client side code, the only way to make them work together is using HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this. But to use server side information you should use AJAX and http requests. This example is just for changing DOM elements.

```
 <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my text color.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}
</script>
```