# onClick event on <a> tag + php

Tags: php

I have a requirement where I am looping through some objects to create  tags and have to open another page after setting some session variables.

```
    for ($i = 0, $count = count($result_array->items); $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $item = $result_array->items[$i];
        ?>
        <a href="" onclick="<?php itemSelected($item); ?>">View more</a>            
        <?php
    }

    function itemSelected($argItem)
    {
        $_SESSION['selected_item'] = $argItem;
        header('Location: ' . 'item-details.php');
    }
    ?>
```

It seems that for every loop rotation, the itemSelected() function is firing up. So basically when I'm loading this page, it is getting redirected to item-details.php.

Why is it so and how to handle that?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the users browser. You can't call PHP directly from JS.

Comment: Not from JS, Its PHP from PHP.... `count($result_array->templates)`.

Comment: _onclick="<?php itemSelected($item); ?>">_ is invalid. You need to use ajax for your desire work.

Comment: So the onClick() function cann't call a php function. It has to call a JS function only? i.e. - the itemSelected() would be written in a script.

Comment: See this [execute-php-function-with-onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick)

Comment: Went through the question. Getting some gist of it. I would prefer the ajax approach.
Right now, I am looking in to find some way to pass some arguments ($item in my case) to the ajax function.
It would be helpful if you post some snippet as an answer, so I might try to mark it as an answer.

Many thanks for your help.