# Submit button inside foreach loop update all table rows instead of one row

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I created this simple function to update a row inside a table called `wp_todos`

```
function update_completed_todos($id,$complete) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'todos';
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM " . $table_name .  " WHERE id = '" .$id."'");
    if (count ($result) > 0) {
        $wpdb->update( 
            $table_name, 
            array(  
                'complete'   =>  $complete, 
            ),
            array( 'id' => $id )
        );
    }
}
```

It simply passes 2 variables: `$id` and `$complete`.

Then I created a `foreach` loop:

```
$todos = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $table_name);
foreach ($todos  as $key => $value) {
     <input id="<?php echo $value->id; ?>" type="submit" onclick="<?php update_completed_todos($value->id, 1); ?>" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Done' ); ?>" />
}
```

As you see it should submit `"1"` to a specific column `complete` in a specific row.
The issue here is when I click on the button it affects all the rows inside the table instead of the target one row. In other word it makes the entire column `complete` taking the value of "1".

Comment: I think you'll find it's updating _before_ you click the button - the updates are being performed as the page renders.  `onclick` can't call PHP like that.  You'll need the javascript to call a function on the server, probably with AJAX.  See the answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19323136), though that's not WordPress specific

Comment: Also, check out [the section of the codex on SQL injection](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).  If your ID is coming from the browser, just concatenating it into a string (in your SELECT) is dangerous - read up on and use `$wpdb->prepare()`

Comment: OK, thanks @Hobo I will check the two references you sent. Also ID does not coming from the browser, it came from the database as you can see I used `$todos = $wpdb->get_results` to query the database.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it _will_ come from the browser (or at least, I assume it will) - you'll have to send it from the browser when you click the button.  And if it is coming from the browser, a malicious user could change it to something unexpected.  Best to get in the habit of using `$wpdb->prepare()` just in case

Comment: [Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/227403/264) is an example of doing something similar in WordPress, using the [AJAX API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).  You should be able to add the PHP code to your theme's functions.php

Comment: @Hobo your last comment somewhat help, thank you.