# Cookies not saving on Android mobile

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I'm using this javascript function to setup a cookie on my site that will show a div wile the cookie isn't setup.

```
function accept_cookies(){
    days=365; // number of days to keep the cookie
    myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    document.cookie = 'cookie_t=1; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
}
```

usage:

```
<a onClick="HideContent('cookies'); accept_cookies()" href="javascript:HideContent('cookies')">
    ok
</a>
```

This method works great on my desktop device but, on my android phone it doesn't work so well. I know this because I click the link several times and the div keeps on showing after it the link saying that is ok.

Comment: Please add `HideContent` source !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH `function HideContent(e){if(e.length<1){return}document.getElementById(e).style.display="none"}`

Comment: I don't see where you check the cookies value in your `HideContent` function ?!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php method "setcookie" to create a Set-Cookie header, that will set a cookie on the client side.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Processes that happens in the server side (php) are much more reliable than on the client side.

Usage example with php and ajax jquery library:

```
<a href="#" onClick="ajaxPost()">active</a>

function ajaxPost(){
   $.post("action.php",{action: "setTheCookie"}, function(result){
    // Do something
   }
}
```

*action.php*

```
checkAction();
function checkAction(){
   if($_POST["action"] == "setTheCookie")
     setCookie("cookie name", "cookie value", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
   exit();
}
```

Comment: How can I do that? can you point an example or a good tutorial? Please don't forget that I need to be set onClick

Comment: you can try this tutorial to setcookie with php:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp

and you need that onClick will make an ajax or get/post action, that will active the php page with the setcookie function.

example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick