# making JavaScript apostrophe work in php line for onclick image change

Tags: javascript, php

The below line of code is not working in my php page causing the page not to load. The line works fine in html and the image appropriately changes

```
        $content[] = '<div id="dealslist" onclick="godea('.$row['id'].');" style="border-bottom:1px solid gray;padding:2px;width:180px;float:left;">
                        <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
                            <h4 style="margin:0;"><span style="float:left;">'.$row['fname'].'</span></h4><div style="width:100%;float:left;"  ><p><b>Address:</b></p><span id="eventaddr" onclick="gomap();" style="color:#1D77EF;">'.$row['addr1'].', '.$row['addr2'].'<br/>'.$row['city'].', '.$row['state'].' '.$row['zip'].'</span></div><br /><p style="margin-bottom:0;">'.substr($row['description'],0,300).'</p>
                        </div>
                                     </div><br /></br><a onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='fav2.png'"><img id="myImage" src="fav.png" style="opacity: 0.7;height:45px;max-width:100px"></a>
                    ';
```

using (\'myImage\').src=\'fav2.png\' also does not work

Comment: Open developer tools and see if you are getting any errors. Might suggest what the problem is!

Comment: @DragomirKolev i am using notepad, i am not sure if that program has developer tools. I am a self taught coder

Comment: Developer tools runs in the browser. Press f12 if you are using chrome. Google how to get dev tools if using other browser as im not sure

Comment: This might answer your questions. Check out the answer on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick

Comment: Post your php part! Not just the html part. The code you posted seems to be valid. So nobody will find an error in it. You need your quotes to be properly escaped. And you should recognize that you wont get those problems is you assign your event handlers with jquery.on(). That should always be the preferred way.

Comment: @steven I added more code, I hope this helps

Comment: I found my own answer, all I had to do is replace the ' with ` @steven @Dragomir Kolev thank you for your help

Comment: @steven  
I found my own answer, all I had to do is replace the ' with ` thank you for your help

Comment: @DragomirKolev  
I found my own answer, all I had to do is replace the ' with ` thank you for your help