# How to call a php function on a html text click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to call php function while call that function I need to pass parameter, when click on some text, It has to call the method called test();
How to do this.

I don't know anything about ajax.I have taken this code to try it.To try I have used simple code it is also not working.

This is Ajax.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <p>Click Me</p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url:"script.php", //the page containing php script
    type: "POST", //request type
    success:function(result){
    alert(result);
    }
  });
});
})
</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

script.php contains,

```
<?php 
function test(){
  echo "Hello";
  }
 ?>
```

how to call php function when user click on some text.where I have to call that test() method. Can Any one help me?

Comment: add `dataType:'Text'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP function with onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick)

Comment: add `test();` in you script.php

Comment: In my code I need to close <head > tag before only.

Comment: You need to include the jquery library file first. https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to call when page called

```
 <?php 
  test()//mind it
  function test(){
    echo "Hello";
  }
 ?>
```

Or use any param like name of action

```
 <?php 
  if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']==1){
      test()//mind it
  }else{
      otherFunc()//mind it
  }
  function test(){
    echo "Hello";
  }
 ?>
```

Set action in url

```
url:"script.php?action=1",
```

Comment: When click "Click me" it is not calling test() method.

Comment: Nothing is working. Give me some suggestions to do this.

Comment: what error you are getting ? in console or network tab ?

Comment: I am getting any error. It is just printing Click. That's all.

Comment: url:"script.php?action=1", . I have tried this it is not working.