# Run python script from html page

Tags: python-2.7

I want to run python script from HTML page ,i have no idea how to do it .
So asking Is it possible to run python script from html button ?, if possible please share the steps .Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use python web frameworks flask, django, web2py .... then you can use python on html

Comment: Try [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python scripts from HTML button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894506/running-python-scripts-from-html-button)