# Why PHP in script don't work

Tags: php, jquery

I am a beginner in PHP, I just need a little bit php in my project.

I want to echo something in a script and it doesn't work. Why?

```
<div id="entree">
        <label>Mot de passe : </label><br><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Inserer Mot de passe" id="motdepasse" onKeyPress="if(event.keyCode == 13) mdp();"/>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="mdp()" value="C'est parti!">
</div>
```

and my script :

```
function mdp()
{
   alert("ok");
   <?php echo "coucou";?>
}
```

Comment: What does "_it don't work_" mean? White page? Errors in console? `<?php echo"coucou">` should be `<?php echo"coucou" ?>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick

Comment: What do you expect to achieve?

Comment: sorry for syntax but i have the right syntax in my real folder, i just forgot it here :)

Comment: i want to put a text in the input, if the text is one of the id in my database, it will redirect him to another page ( like a save)

Comment: Was a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like this way :

```
function mdp()
{
  var str = "<?php echo 'coucou';?>";
  alert(str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it work with the echo, i gonna see if my real idea work with this :)

Comment: @PaulTanné If this answer solved your question you are welcome to accept it

Answer (score 0):

There are few corrections here:

```
<?php echo "coucou";?> /* missed at the end `;?` */
```

For JS multiple statements without using `;` will result in syntax error, try this

```
alert(<?=var_export("coucou",true)?>);
```