# Php syntax. How do I get this code correct in onclick event?

Tags: php, html

[image]

I have two `<a></a>` tags which holds the `onclick` event and has PHP code in it. Obviously I need them to work. What those links do - switch between months. Here are the links.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<select name="month_dropdown" class="month_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo $this->getAllMonths($dateMonth); ?></select>
<select name="year_dropdown" class="year_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo $this->getYearList($dateYear); ?></select>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

As you can see I have the `$this->` pointer in `<select></select>` tags which allows it to be in use because I am using classes and there has to be the pointer there I assume. So how do I get the tags to work? When I add the `$this->` pointer to the `onclick` event in front of `getCalendar` the PHP code just breaks down.

Do I have to use some other method in order to achieve what I am after?

Comment: Edit your code to make more readable please

Comment: It's important to remember that PHP doesn't know anything about `onclick` events and vice versa; all you're doing is *building some HTML*, which as far as PHP is concerned is just text. So it doesn't make any difference *to PHP* whether the code is in an `onclick` element or a `marquee` tag.

Comment: I reopened (silly me), but I think you should still read this: [Execute PHP function with onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick)

Comment: Oh I see, I then just use AJAX I have tempered with it but this will be a new chalange for me. How silly of me that I did not know that php does not work on onclick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-variable `$this` is available when a method is called from within an object context. If your code is not part of class definition, you must create object first:

`$obj = new Class();`

Then use class methods with:

`$obj->getAllMonths($dateMonth);`.

You can read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) about PHP classes.

Answer (score 0):

check this code. you are add `'<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>'`  here single cotetion remove this.

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div',<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>,<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>

 <select name="month_dropdown" class="month_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo $this->getAllMonths($dateMonth); ?></select>

 <select name="year_dropdown" class="year_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo $this->getYearList($dateYear); ?></select>

 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div',<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>,<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```