# HTML SQL server connection using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a HTML form and I want to use the results to filter the data available in a SQL file. I'm trying to connect to a local MySQL server but It doesn't work, i don't achieve to enter in the table() function.

I use the following code:

```
<form id="form_id" action="food_values.php" method="post" name="myform">
...
  <input onclick="table" type="button" value="Submit">

</form>
```

The php file contains the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
function table(){
    echo ("INSIDE");
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root"," ");
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    else {
        echo "CONNECTED";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't show anything... Do you know where is the error?

Comment: You are treating the PHP as if it were javascript, which it is not. See the following for an example on how to properly submit a form to a PHP script: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php.

Comment: you have _defined_ the function, but didn't _call_ it. In this case you need to put `table();` after the whole `function table(){... } ` thing

Comment: Please modify you code both html and php. A lot of things are out of place. What is onclick doing there?

Comment: @cypherabe It is unclear if these are separate files or not, and I realised after what you meant so I deleted my comment.

Comment: Please don't mix `mysql` (which is deprecated!) and `mysqli`

Comment: ***IMPORTANT***: [Please read this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Do **NOT** use `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute a PHP-Function with "onclick".
[Execute PHP function with onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick)

With a form,  you load the whole .php-file if you click on the submit.

The following code should work for you:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    echo ("INSIDE");
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root"," ");
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    else {
        echo "CONNECTED";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the HTML

```
<form id="form_id" action="food_values.php" method="post" name="myform">
...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input onclick="table" type="button" value="Submit">
```

into

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

As the `action` in form takes care of where to direct the data in php.

and in 'food_values.php' page you dont have to define function as its not javascript.

```
   <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

This will connect the database.
And for validation of the form follow the SQL commands. For futher detail visit
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Comment: There was a function definition, not a class.