# How can we apply both JavaScript and PHP to a button?

Tags: javascript, php

When I click a button:

1. I need the JavaScript to perform some function.
2. Also run PHP code as well.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: multiple options, tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call PHP functions by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is only run by the server and responds to requests like clicking on a link/button (GET) or submitting a form (POST).

HTML & JavaScript is only run in someone's browser.

```
<html>
<?php
  function PhpFunction() {
    echo 'A php function';
  }

  if (isset($_GET['JsFunction'])) {
    PhpFunction();
  }
?>

Hello there!
<a href='index.php?JsFunction=true'>Run PHP Function On Click Of This Link</a>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But is there a way to run both javascript and php.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively ,
You can create a ajax request to run a php code in your server..

Answer (score 0):

Ajax can help you to send an asynchronous request to the server that php (or other) can catch, in this way you can implement and play with some callback functions

```
$.ajax({
       url : "yourScript.php", // the resource where youre request will go throw
       type : "POST", // HTTP verb
       data : { action: 'myActionToGetHits', param2 : myVar2 },
       dataType: "json",
       success : function (response) {
          //in your case, you should return from the php method some fomated data that you  //need throw the data var object in param
             data = toJson(response) // optional
            //heres your code

       },
       error : //some code, 
       complete : //...
});
```

in your php script, you'll receive the request posted throw the superglobal vars like POST (for this example)

```
<?php

$action = (string)$_POST['action']; //this is unsecure, its just for the example

if("myActionToGetHits" == $action) {

 //here you have to call your php function and so on..
$data = hitsMonth();
echo $data;
exit;
}
```

here is html

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:functionName(arg1, arg2);">
```

This is a basic example to do it, there are lots of ways to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have javascript do the submit:

```
function button1() {
  // js code here
  var formelt = document.getElementById("form1");
  formelt.submit(); // this will submit the form to server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example =>

```
<button class="btn-test">Btn Test</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery('.btn-test').click(function() {
        js_do_something();
        php_do_something();
    });

    function js_do_something() {
       console.log('something done from js');
    }

    function php_do_something() {
        console.log('something done from php');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'you_php_file.php',
            data: {param: 'btn-test-click'},
            success: function () {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you have how to execute a php function with on Onclick.

[Execute PHP function with onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick)

You can execute a Javascript function assuming you´re using jQuery like this:

```
jQuery('#id-button').on('click', function(){
    // your function body
});
```