# How to create a button to show only on sale products?

Tags: woocommerce

I know I can modify the query to show only the on sale products in the loop like this

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_query','show_only_on_sale_products');
function show_only_on_sale_products( $q )
{
    $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
    $q->set( 'post__in', $product_ids_on_sale );
}
```

How can I make a button where I call this? So I can toggle with it.

PS: I know I can use a shortcode for it but I don't like this solution:

```
[products limit="4" orderby="popularity" class="quick-sale" on_sale="true" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have your PHP function here then if I am correct, all you want is to execute this function on a button click, if yes, kindly check [Execute PHP function with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick) post.

I believe it will help you. Have a good day.

Comment: Not really, what I need is after the button is clicked the product part of the page is reloaded and the hook is added to the query that will filter the data. I need ajax for this but I don’t know what url and action to pass.

Comment: I want to add a button in the header that will filter my products using ajax.